# applying a Function to Each element in an array (O'Reilly cookbook example)

Tags: php, arrays, html-entities

for nested data.

I tried

```
<?php

$names = array('firstnames' => array("Baba", "Billy"),
'lastnames' => array("O'Riley", "O'Reilly"));

array_walk_recursive($names, function (&value, $key) {
    $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QOUTES);
})

foreach ($names as $nametypes) {
    foreach ($nametypes as $name) {
        print "$name\n";

    }
}



?>
```

(An example from the book O'reilly PHP Cookbook 3rd Edition) page 148

but I keep getting a message

T_String, expecting T_Variable

Comment: Off-topic: Typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `&$value` instead of `&value`
use ENT_QUOTES instead of ENT_QOUTES

Answer (score 1):

Typos in your code (ENT_QUOTES, $value):

```
array_walk_recursive($names, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
});


foreach ($names as $nametypes) {
    foreach ($nametypes as $name) {
        print "$name\n";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working.

thanks all

```
<?php

$names = array('firstnames' => array("Baba", "Billy"),
'lastnames' => array("O'Riley", "O'Reilly"));

array_walk_recursive($names, function (&$value, $key) {
    $value = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
});

foreach ($names as $nametypes) {
    foreach ($nametypes as $name) {
        print "$name\n";

    }
}



?>
```